# Nav Tag, The best way to redirect to another page

Tags: html

I am a little bit newbie in the web development.

I’m creating a simple web page with a Nav Tag navigation, but I’m not pretty sure which is the best way to redirect to another pages.

For example I have the menu: Home, Services, Contact and when you click in one of them you will go to a page with the properly information.

I have seen this structure:

```
<nav>
  <a href="/html/">HTML</a> |
  <a href="/css/">CSS</a> |
  <a href="/js/">JavaScript</a> |
  <a href="/jquery/">jQuery</a>
</nav>
```

But where do you go ? To another page or a section on the same page?

I would like see the same original page and when you click in one item of the menu only changes the bottom of the web page.

So what way do you recommend to do this ?
I hope you could help me, thank you so much.

Comment: Why don't you try changing the `src` of an `<iframe>` that is kept on the same page? or you may need to use ajax. And I don't think its possible to change the contents of the page only with html

Comment: You are confusing many terms. The navigation using the `<a>`-tags isn't the same thing as HTTP-redirect. I suggest you read more tutorials or some book about web-development, HTTP Protocol and HTML. But to answer: In this piece of HTML, e.g. the link `<a href="/jquery/">jQuery</a>` would work only if you had a file `jquery/index.html` or your server resolved the URL in some more dynamic manner (routing etc.)

Comment: You could use php's `include()` to have static and dynamic (not static/dynamically loaded, but "static" in the sense that that portion of the page doesn't change, and this might also help load faster because of browser caches(?)) portions of a page; but to load only a part of a page, you would definitely need to look into AJAX (or jQuery, which uses AJAX).

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
<a href="#ex1" class="go">"Any Text you want, in you case: "go to bottom""</a></l>
```

After this create class at the botton of the page with same id

```
<div class="bottom" id="ex1">
```

If you want to go to bottom by clicking to the link add javascript at the end of the .html file just before "/body" closes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.go").click(function () {
    var elementClick = $(this).attr("href");
    var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
    $('html,body').animate( { scrollTop: destination }, 700 );
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

If you want to redirect and go to another page, create html file in the same directory(same folder). Then add a link

```
<a href="New.html">"Any text you want, in your case: go to another page"</a>
```